# How to get checked checkbox value and store it array variable in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have created array list and listing it as multiple check box. From that if i select i'm storing into the array variable and if I uncheck its need to be remove from array. I tried this is working for but while uncheck value is not removing from the array variable.

Here is my code below and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Silambarasan_sundaram/cp0dwg5k/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <lable ng-repeat="list in lists">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" ng-model="lst" value="{{list.vl}}" ng-change="change()">
    {{list.vl}} <br>
    </lable>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.lists = [
        {'vl' : 1},
        {'vl' : 2},
        {'vl' : 3},
        {'vl' : 4},
        {'vl' : 5},
    ];

    $scope.lst = [];
    $scope.change = function(){
        $scope.lst.push('2');
        console.log($scope.lst);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass data in `ngChange` that you need to decide if you want to push or splice.

HTML

```
<lable ng-repeat="list in lists">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="active" ng-change="change(list, active)" >
</lable>
```

SCRIPT

```
$scope.change = function(list, active){
    if (active)
        $scope.lst.push(list);
    else
        $scope.lst.splice($scope.lst.indexOf(list), 1);
};
```

Note that the current value for each item is stored in a variable `active` on the isolated scope. If you need the value in your model, just bind likes this:

```
<lable ng-repeat="list in lists">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="list.active" ng-change="change(list, active)" >
</lable>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ruzw4Lfb/8/

Comment: How to get value of the index?

Comment: @Silambu $index is magic of `ngRepeat`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat  I am not sure what you want to store in the array. In my example I pushed the `$index`. I guess that's not what you really want, but it' s very unclear from your question.

Comment: Don't rely on $index because it will not work while applying filter on ng-repeat. Just for info ;)

Comment: @squiroid You're right. I think it's better to just pass the information to `change` that is actually needed. I didn't really understand his intention from the question.

Comment: @Silambu Updated answer and fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Use push and pop of array

While change() send two values first is it selected which is provided by ng-model and second the value you want to push or slice(remove).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" ng-model="lst" value="{{list.vl}}" ng-change="change(lst,list.vl)">

$scope.change = function(check,value){
        if(check){
            $scope.lst.push(value);
        }else{
             $scope.lst.splice($scope.lst.indexOf(value), 1);
        }
    };
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cp0dwg5k/4/)**

Hope it help :)

Comment: @Silambu You will not need the `value="{{list.vl}}"` anymore. Just remove it and your code will be more a lot cleaner.

Comment: Sorry to say! I selected all check box from that if I uncheck second check box it is not removing second check box value from that array. I need to remove unchecked check box value from the array.

Comment: @Silambu silly mistake i used pop instead of slice it :P

Answer (score 1):

I also created a solution for your problem in a different way. I made something simple than yours. This may help you. Check the example code below:

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.lists = [
            {'vl' : 1, 'state' : false},
            {'vl' : 2, 'state' : false},
            {'vl' : 3, 'state' : false},
            {'vl' : 4, 'state' : false},
            {'vl' : 5, 'state' : false}
        ];

        $scope.change = function(id){
            $scope.lists[id].state = !$scope.lists[id].state;
            console.log($scope.lists);
        };
    });
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <lable ng-repeat="list in lists">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{list.vl}}" ng-click="change($index)">
    {{list.vl}} <br>
    </lable>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first I assume taht you synthax of list is incorrect, as you should have list**s**:

```
 $scope.lists = [
            {'vl' : 1},
            {'vl' : 2},
            {'vl' : 3},
            {'vl' : 4},
            {'vl' : 5},
        ];
```

Then, this is unecessary :   `$scope.lst = {};` as you can affect the model of each item of your list like :

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" ng-model="item.lst" value="{{list.vl}}" ng-change="change()">
```

note Item.lst that will update yout lists model.

after several change you will have :

```
 $scope.lists = [
                {'vl' : 1, 'lst' : value},
                {'vl' : 2, 'lst' : value},
                {'vl' : 3, 'lst' : value},
                {'vl' : 4, 'lst' : value},
                {'vl' : 5, 'lst' : value},
            ];
```